# django REST ModelSerializer serialization issue

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Good morning everybody!

I've a problem with django REST ModelSerializer.

This is my serializer:

```
class TransactionPayOutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Users.objects.all(), slug_field='unique_id', allow_null=True)
    wallet = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all(), slug_field='wallet_id')
    bank_account = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=BankAccount.objects.all(), slug_field='bank_account_id')

    class Meta:
        model = PayOut
        fields = ('author', 'wallet', 'amount',
                  'currency', 'bank_account')


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            super(TransactionPayOutSerializer,self).__init__(kwargs.get('instance'))
        else:
            self.merchant = kwargs.pop('merchant')
            super(TransactionPayOutSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def validate(self, data):
        print 'Inside serializer validate(), data:'
        print data
        wallet = data['wallet']
        user_wallet = UserWallets.objects.get(wallet=wallet) 
        if self.merchant != user_wallet.merchant:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Wallet not found")
        wallet.fetch()
        if wallet.balance < data['amount']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not enough founds in wallet") 
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print 'Inside TransactionPayOutSerializer create():'
        print 'Validated data:'
        print validated_data
        pay_out = PayOut(**validated_data)
        user_wallet = UserWallets.objects.get(wallet=validated_data['wallet'])
        pay_out.author = user_wallet.user
        pay_out.merchant = self.merchant
        pay_out.save()
        return pay_out
```

It works perfectly but my problem is:

When the serializer is used for a get request (serializer.data) it's perfect.
But when the serializer is used for a post request (TransactionPayOutSerializer(data=request.DATA)) it absolutely wants the 'user' parameter in the JSON.
What is the best way to keep serialzer.data return 'user' representation  making TransactionPayOutSerializer(data=request.DATA) works without receiving 'user' as parameter inside JSON post request?
I should use simple serializers instead of ModelSerializers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> [Serializer Fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)
>
> `read_only` Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when
>   serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or
>   updating an instance during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to `False`
>
> `write_only` Set this to True to ensure that the field may be used when
>   updating or creating an instance, but is not included when serializing
>   the representation.
>
> Defaults to `False`